# Why inputRef in CurrencyTextField return the error inputRef.current is null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, focus

I'm trying to focus on the second 'CurrentTextField' after the first 'CurrentTextField' change your value,
but return the error 'inputRef.current is null'

```
import React, {useRef } from 'react';
import CurrencyTextField from "@unicef/material-ui-currency-textfield";

export default function Clientes() {
   let refInput = useRef(null)

   return(
      <div>
         <CurrencyTextField 
          onChange={(e) => refInput.current.focus()}
         />

         <CurrencyTextField 
          inputRef={refInput}
         />
      </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

I checked again and saw that uses the `TextField` component from `material-ui/core` which has a `inputProps` prop, so this will work

```
  <CurrencyTextField inputProps={{ref:refInput}} />
```

**UPDATE**

I just checked the `CurrencyTextField` source code and it doesn't handle refs

---

Since you are using the custom component `CurrencyTextField` you should check if it handles references, when using normal HTML tags you would use the prop `ref`

```
export default function Clientes() {
   let refInput = useRef(null)

   return(
      <div>
         <CurrencyTextField 
          onChange={(e) => refInput.current.focus()}
         />

         <-- normal input will work -->
         <input  
          ref={refInput}
         />
      </div>
   )
}
```

Try to do it like if it were a regular HTML tag to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

That looks kind of weird. I checked the React documentation and looks good [useRef React](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). Maybe can bring us more details about the library because maybe could be related to your problem